# Get full DOM stack as a string

Tags: javascript, dom, properties

I want to get the full DOM stack as a string. As an example, please open Chrome, press F12 and type "document.all". This object represents the full DOM. I want to convert this object as a string. In Chrome you're able to explore the object, expand sections and view their content in the web debugger console. Is there any possibility to convert document.all as a string? Or a similar solution with gives me the full DOM stack? I don't just want the innerHTML/outerHTML, I want the content of literally everything what's defined in the current DOM. Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

EDIT: Okay, I think my question is kind of confusing, sorry for that. To clarify this: I want to get **every property** of **every object** which is defined, including stuff like "document.location", "document.location.hash", "window.innerHeight", "document.body.innerHTML", and so on, by using JavaScript.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: Please specify what programming context you want "the full DOM... as a string".  Putting a javascript tag on the question doesn't much clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Try something like `var ignoreKeys = ['parentNode', 'ownerNode', 'previousElementSibling', 'ownerElement', 'offsetParent', 'ownerDocument', 'parentElement', 'previousSibling'];
JSON.stringify(document.all, function(key, value){ console.log(key); return ignoreKeys.indexOf(key) >= 0 ? undefined : value });`

Comment: Try the demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qAKcf/1/

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there's no way to get every property of every object.

In at least some browsers (Chrome, for instance), you can get most of the **DOM** with `outerHTML` on `documentElement` (the root element, e.g., `html`):

```
var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

You'd have to check whether your other target browsers do. At a minimum, they'll have `innerHTML` on `body`:

```
var bodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
```

But in terms of the other things, I don't believe there's any way to get every property of every object. For instance, you can find the properties on `window` like this:

```
var key;
for (key in window) {
    // ...'key' is the property name, window[key] is the value...
}
```

...but that will only give you *enumerable* properties, not non-enumerable ones. And of course, you'd have to recurse into objects to get *their* properties (allowing for the fact that you can get to an object in more than one way — for example, `window === window.window` and there's also `top`, `self`, etc. to worry about; and similarly for `document.all`, `document.forms`, ...).

So unfortunately, while you can get a **lot** of the information you're talking about, I don't believe you can get it *all*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want the innerHTML or outerHTML. I want the _full_ DOM stack, this means I want to get every string which is defined in the current DOM.

Comment: @user2486107: What makes you think `outerHTML` on the document element doesn't have that? I mean, I guess it wouldn't have the `doctype`, but...

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: outerHTML is only the content of one property defined in the current DOM stack. I want everything. For example, outerHTML won't contain the content of "document.location.hash", or "window.innerHeight". I want to get everything, the whole DOM tree at it's current state.

Comment: @user2486107: `window.innerHeight` isn't part of the DOM tree. It's just a propery of the `window` object, which is a different thing. You're quite right that `outerHTML` won't have expandos and such. I'm fairly certain there is no one place you can go to get **all** of that information. `outerHTML` will give you most of it, but I don't think there's anything that's going to give you **all** of it. Even if you used `for-in` on `window`, you'd miss out any non-enumerable properties... (And expandos on individual elements.)

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: I adjusted my question.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem is, I really need invariably **every single property** which is defined.

Comment: @user2486107: Sorry, but what you "need" is almost certainly impossible. You'll have to take a different approach. For instance, if I do this: `Object.defineProperty(window, "foo", { value: 42 });`, the `foo` property won't show up in `for-in` loops. To find it, you'd basically have to test the `window` object for every possible property identifier (which is, in practical terms, impossible).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this yourself using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), which will even include non-enumerable properties. I made a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/736jf/63/) showing how this might be done.